# Why is the Jacobi Matrix not a matrix?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, manifolds

In a textbook im reading about manifolds they write:

> Let $W \subset \mathbb{ R } ^n $ be an open set and $ F : W \rightarrow \mathbb{ R } ^ m $ a $C ^ k $ function such that for every point $ p \in M := F ^ { -1 }( 0  $ the derivative $DF( p ): \mathbb{ R } ^ n \rightarrow \mathbb{ R } ^ m$ has rang $m $. Then $ M $ is a $C ^ k $-manifold with dimension $d = n - m$.

Shouldnt the derivate be a function from the type $ DF(p) : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R } ^ { m \times n }$ ?

The first time I saw this I gussed it was a mistake in the textbook but it seems to appear multiple times afterwards. Do I get something wrong there?

Comment: The derivative is a linear approximation to your function, therefore it has to be from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. Where is your idea that the matrix should be to $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ coming from?

Comment: No, a point $p$ has already been plugged in.

Comment: You are wrong. The derivative is a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and its matrix (for the usual bases) is the jacobian matrix.

Comment: When we have a function $F: \mathbb{R } ^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R } ^ m $ in general. The derivative is the jacobian matrix which forms a $m \times n $ matrix right? Isnt the derivative then a function from $ \mathbb{R }^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n }$ ?

Comment: The matrix is $m\times n$, yes. $A$ say. We then take a vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and what we get is $Ax\in \mathbb{R}^m$. So the derivative is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: To repeat, yes, the derivative is a matrix--you're right--but only AFTER a point has been plugged in.  Compare $DF(p)$ vs $DF$.

Comment: Oh okay. The difference between $DF(p)$ and $DF$ clearly makes a difference. Thanks for your help.